# connection.getCatalog() returns null for Oracle

Tags: java, database, oracle

When using oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver to connect an Oracle database, connection.getCatalog() returns null. For MySql database, it returns the database name. Is there any way to get oracle database name easily?

Comment: Did you try `connection.getDatabaseMetadata().getSchemas()`?

Comment: Minor nit to @Jim Garrison 's comment - `connection.getMetaData().getSchemas()`  is the correct method spelling.

Answer (score 1):

Because in Oracle a user equals a "schema". So try

DatabaseMetaData.getUserName()